# wmode (transparent) for CGI rather than flash

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cgi, wmode

I have a CGI in an object (from an ethernet webcam) which works fine for most browsers but not for IE (10). The problem is that my menu should be shown above that element but it isn't. I know of  but that - as it seems - only applies to SWF sources in an object. Also, zindex could not help.

In other words, this

```
<object width="640" height="480" id="Player" classid="CLSID:..." codebase="http://my.server/activex/AMC.cab#version=2,0,22,0" style="z-index: 104;">
<PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="16933">
<PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="12700">
<PARAM NAME="MediaURL" VALUE="http://my.server/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480">
<PARAM NAME="UIMode" VALUE="none">
<PARAM NAME="MediaType" VALUE="mjpeg-unicast">
<PARAM NAME="MPEG2VideoDecodingMode" VALUE="3">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<p>Error</p></object>
```

does hide an absolutely positioned menu dropdown that should be shown above it.

Any ideas on that?

Best regards,
Mario

Comment: The most common piece of advice to new posters here: attach the relevant code. People are going to want more info to try to help you.

Comment: Now let's try putting that in the question.

Comment: @sphanley Any content suggestions as well? Would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm afraid not -- I just ended up here through the review queue for new user's first posts. You're looking much better now on including code though, so perhaps someone will be able to help.